# How to detect only doc, docx, xls, xlsx, txt, ppt, pps and pdf files

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to upload files in firebase storage:

```
if ($('#arquivo')[0].files.length > 0){

                file = $('#arquivo')[0].files[0];

                var metadata = {
                    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
                };

                var uploadTask = imagesRef.child('documentos/' + file.name).put(file, metadata);

                uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
                    console.log('state changed')
                    //console.log(snapshot)
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log('error')
                    console.log(error)
                    closeLoader();
                }, function() {
                    console.log('arquivo uploaded')
                    downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;

                    documento.arquivo = downloadURL

                    documentosRef.child(keyDocumento).update(documento);
                    window.location = "/documentos?estado=updated_success"; 
                });
}
```

I would like these files to be only extensions doc, docx, xls, xlsx, txt, ppt, pps and pdf files

How i can do this?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to check to see if `file.name` ends with one of the following file extensions before uploading it?

Comment: Yes ... and only allow to upload if the file ends with these extensions.

Comment: This sounds like a javascript question, not a Firebase question.  Retagging.

Comment: Maybe just check with a regex before you even hit your firebase stuff. Since an invalid type will trigger a frontend warning anyway. Something like: `(/\.(doc|docx|xls|xlsx|txt|ppt|pps|pdf)$/i).test(file.name)`